# Spring not initializing one object per session

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hello guys I have big problem here. Sessions in my controller are not working right. My goal is to have one **comp** object for each session but I get every time the same comp (comp is initialized just once and not per session).

Example:

**Mozilla:**
Firstly my comp is null. When in one screen I select one comp, new comp is initialized and everything is OK.

**Chrome:**
When I get to the screen where I want to select my comp is already initialized (Mozilla comp) so when I select my comp, comp from mozilla is overridden.

**Controller :**

```
package com.test;
@SessionAttributes({"comp", "userDetails"})    
@Controller    
@RequestMapping(value="/arep") 
public class ARepController{
@Autowired AdmUserDetails userDetails;

@Autowired
private ARepService aRepService;

@Autowired
private Component comp;


}
```

**Component:**

```
package com.test;
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "session")
public class Component implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 587780902400791285L;

private List<Component Item> items = new ArrayList<ComponentItem>();

private Integer length;
private Integer height;
private Integer depth;

public Component () {
}

public Component (Integer length, Integer height,Integer depth) {
     this.length = length;
     this.height = height;
     this.depth = depth;
}
}
```

**root-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd" >

<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test" >
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

</beans:beans>
```

I copied just the code that seemed crucial to me. In advance I would like to thank anyone who will take his time for helping me out here.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make your controller bean session scoped

Comment: If I do that all objects of Controller are session scoped and not just comp object. I want just comp object session scoped.

Comment: No, not all, only those that are defined with session scope.
Basically I think this is not what you're expecting. Session attributes is used to keep data between several requests until session is invalidated, so I guess your Component should not be a spring bean at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have slightly confused the use of M and C as in MVC. Generally the controller should be a singleton, and as a result cannot contain user data. The userDetails and comp in your controller belong in the model, and in most Spring MVC implementations they will be stored in the session. Your aRepService looks like a service shared by all users, so it definitely belongs in the controller.

Spring can create your model bean (I believe), but this is a simple task, so I always do it manually. This also avoids the somewhat heavy overhead of Spring bean creation.